# Converting string to time

Tags: c#, string, datetime, time, format

I have string like this:"0:385" (first number is seconds, next numbers are milliseconds), I want to use in datagridview with sorting like numbers (not like strings) so I am trying to make DateTime from string but I am not sure how exactly do this. I know I should use method Parse (or ParseExact) but when I tried it it says "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.". I read some articles about that but I am not sure how exactly use IFormatProvider and next arguments.
Thanks for help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the following: `TimeSpan.Parse("0:0:0.365")`

But you must format the string like this: [d.]hh:mm:ss[.ff] (The day [d] and fractional seconds [ff] are optional)

See [TimeSpan.Parse Method on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se73z7b9%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Thansk, it helps, I think i must repair string to right format.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are missing day, month and year from your string, you will not be able to parse it to a DateTime.

Try using a [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) instead.

Comment: I tried TimeSpan before but when I use method Parse it says: "The TimeSpan could not be parsed because at least one of the hours, minutes, or seconds components is outside its valid range."

Answer (score 0):

TimeSpan.Parse("0:0:0" + str.Replace(':', '.'))

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

```
 var dt = new DateTime(2010, 06, 26); // time is zero by default
 string currTime = "19:04:06";//dateTimePicker1.Value.TimeOfDay.ToString();
 var tm = TimeSpan.Parse(currTime);
 var fullDt = dt + tm;
```